# Tip of my Tongue: some word that means fear out of respect

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm looking for some word that means to fear someone out of respect. I feel like the mafia comes to mind? Or something of the kind. For example, someone excelling in an area, and demanding(?) admiration. Sorry if I can't provide more of an explanation.

Comment: Well, the word "awesome" comes to mind.  But you really need to give more of an example of the use of the term.

Comment: I agree with a Yahoo Answers post asking this same question where someone posted that this is actually somewhat of an oxymoron; if you fear someone, that's fear, not respect. If you truly respect someone, you don't fear them.

I feel that the concept you seem to be looking for, having mentioned the Mafia is **intimidation** possibly?

Comment: Good for @HotLicks for suggesting "awesome," whether or not it turns out to be exactly the word you want. Few know that the word "awe" has its roots in fear. (http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=awe)

Comment: Do you really mean 'fear out of respect', or instead 'respect out of fear', which seems more apt?

Comment: In some contexts "star struck".

Comment: @JohnClifford Fear and respect are two different things, but the same person can inspire both emotions. For instance a leader or employer may be respected for his (or her) achievements but feared for his (or her) short temper and the extreme punishments he (or she) hands out. Fear does not come from respect nor true respect from fear. The nearest thing to respect a dangerous but despicable person can get is the simulation of respect. Unfortunately that seems to be enough for some people.

Comment: The word "reverence" means to treat with a deep respect, to show awe. 
We could say we have reverence for the law, the president.
However, this is more about admiration than leaning towards fear.

I understand the question because I've struggled to find the same word when it comes to explaining school children & their lack of respect at school.

Sometimes children need to have respect/fear that leans them towards the right path.
It's the type of fear we have when we think a police car has put it's sirens up because of us. The fear/worry of breaking the law. 
"Scared of losing my job"

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for **deference**?

> Definition: respectful submission or yielding to the judgment,
>   opinion, will, etc., of another. When you show deference to someone,
>   you make a gesture of respect.
>
> For example: Sure you wear ripped jeans to school every day, but you
>   don't wear them to your grandmother's house out of deference to her.

Answer (score -2):

I use fear and respect the way we use borrow and lent ...(Kind of two arrows in one circle pointing to the half that makes the one part of the circle and vice versa )